# How can I optimize these elseifs?

Tags: lua, switch-statement, lua-table

I'm working on a leveling and experience system in lua and I was wondering how could I optimize and maybe transform these elseifs in a lua table. The idea is to check if mylevel is less or equal to a defined maxlevel to use different multipliers depending on your level

```
local mylevel = 1
local experience = 50

if mylevel and experience then
    if mylevel <= 10 then
        multiplier = 1
    elseif mylevel <= 15 then
        multiplier = 2
    elseif mylevel <= 25 then
        multiplier = 3
    elseif mylevel <= 35 then
        multiplier = 4
    elseif mylevel <= 45 then
        multiplier = 5
    elseif mylevel <= 80 then
        multiplier = 6
    elseif mylevel <= 100 then
        multiplier = 7
    elseif mylevel > 100 then
        multiplier = 8
    end

end
```

Comment: Since the answers became quite optimization focused: you could also define your leveling with a function, e.g. `exp = 10 + level ^ 2`. Solve for level and you have O(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### When to optimize

First off: Do you really need to optimize? First benchmark and verify whether there is a performance issue. Often asymptotically suboptimal constructs are in practice optimal or at least "good enough" for small numbers due to overhead. Given your small elseif chain of about ten branches, this might very well be the case. I'd also imagine that (at least in simpler cases) LuaJIT might be able to perform optimizations to achieve sublinear asymptotic runtime (f.E. I'd expect a switch-like construct with many equality comparisons to become something like a jump table when the code is JIT compiled; it probably won't nest comparisons intelligently though, esp. since there can be a metamethod involved and order matters). **There probably is no need for optimization here.**

If you want to switch to a data-driven design for maintenance reasons, that's a different matter. But even there it might be argued that the code in its current form is straightforward and readable.

Bottom line: I see no need to touch your code (yet). You can very well keep it simple as-is; only if you are to add (many) more levels is when you should consider "proper" data structures.

Note also that you can replace your last `elseif` with simply an `else`, assuming `<=` is sane.

### How to optimize

#### Binary Search

##### InSync's answer

Gets the job done in asymptoptically logarithmic time. Has significant overhead though.

##### An improved version

It is indeed preferable to store levels and their corresponding multipliers *out of band*:

```lua
local levels = {10, 15, 25, 35, 45, 80, 100}
local multipliers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

then binary search on levels and use the returned insertion index to find the corresponding multiplier.

The reduced overhead is twofold:

- Assumedly less memory consumption: Tables in Lua are *heavy*; they need to keep track of the length of their hash and list part as well as a possible metatable. Using tables for simple pairs is highly memory inefficient.
- Assumedly better performance: This eliminates the indirection of having to first look up a pointer to the pair, then having to look up the first element of that pair on the heap. It should also improve the cache locality during the last few steps of the binary search, since nearby values may already be in the cache.

##### Code is data, data is code

I conjure that it would be most efficient to express the binary search directly through nested `if`s. That way you get rid of just about any and all indirection.

This is how may write it given your `if`-`elseif`-`else` chain:

```lua
if mylevel <= 35 then
    if mylevel <= 15 then
        if mylevel <= 10 then
            multiplier = 1
        else
            multiplier = 2
        end
    else
        if mylevel <= 25 then
           multiplier = 3
        else
           multiplier = 4
    end
else
    if mylevel <= 80 then
        if mylevel <= 45 then
            multiplier = 5
        else
            multiplier = 6
        end
    else
        if mylevel <= 100 then
           multiplier = 7
        else
           multiplier = 8
    end
end
```

This is of course not particulary maintainable: It is in fact hardcoding a (reasonably) balanced binary search tree into your code. You could however write yourself some code to generate this code.

#### Lookup Array

The alternative to a binary search is a simple table which maps from levels to multipliers. Since this is practically an array, access will be optimal - O(1). However you'll need to waste O(n) memory where n is the number of levels up to the upper bound after which you just return a constant max - 100 in your case. This might look as follows:

```lua
local multipliers = {}
local idx = 0
local function add_multipliers(levels, mult)
    for _ = 1, levels do
        idx = idx + 1
        multipliers[idx] = mult
    end
end
add_multipliers(10, 1) -- first ten levels have multiplier 1, and so on...
add_multipliers(5, 2) -- next five levels have 2
add_multipliers(10, 3)
add_multipliers(10, 4)
add_multipliers(10, 5)
add_multipliers(35, 6)
add_multipliers(20, 7)
```

now your function becomes trivial:

```lua
local function get_multiplier(level)
    if level > 100 then return 8 end
    return multipliers[level]
end
```

or, as Nifim points out, simply

```lua
local function get_multiplier(level)
    return multipliers[level] or 8
end
```

since `multipliers[level]` will be `nil` when `level` is out of bounds, thus `8` conceptually is a "default" value (small caveat: this might mask mistakes such as passing `level = nil` or `level = 0`; it would return `8` for those, whereas the previous solution would error or return `nil`)

This is very likely to be both simpler and faster than a binary search. Use this if your numbers are small, as in your example.

Comment: When doing a benchmark this improved the performance, thank you very much. Will be implementing this.

Comment: @QuinnHumpreys btw, I've updated this for a thorough comparison of the possible approaches. Have fun benchmarking and verifying (or disproving?) my estimates, claims and conjectures :)

Comment: if `level` will never be negative, it seems to me that doing `return multipliers[level] or 8` would be a bit cleaner and not require the knowledge of where the level table ends within the `get_multiplier`. also I like the idea of hard coding a bst into a chain of if statement that is kinda nifty.

Comment: @Nifim agreed. I was under the influence of the `elseif` :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a binary search function which has O(log n) time complexity:

```lua
local levels = {
  {10, 1},
  {15, 2},
  {25, 3},
  {35, 4},
  {45, 5},
  {80, 6},
  {100, 7}
}

local function get_multiplier(user_level)
  local low = 1
  local high = #levels

  while low <= high do
    local middle = math.floor((low + high) / 2)

    if levels[middle][1] < user_level then
      low = middle + 1
    else
      high = middle - 1
    end
  end

  return levels[low] and levels[low][2] or levels[#levels][2] + 1
end
```

Try it:

```lua
local mylevel = 121

local multiplier = get_multiplier(mylevel)

print(multiplier)  -- 8
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, this actually works. I was wondering now what about if multipliers were different than +1, let's say for example less than level 10 = 100, then more than level 11 = 555, and so on?

Comment: I just made it creating a table called multipliers with the multipliers for level and then just retuning multipliers[low].

local levels = {10, 15, 25, 35, 45, 80, 100}
local multipliers = {100,500,1500,3000,5500,8000,10000}

return multipliers[low]

Do you think this would go better in the performance side than just using simple elseifs?

Comment: @QuinnHumpreys Yes. n cases means O(n), while binary search always result in O(log n).

Comment: Note: In practice this will be much, much slower, esp. with LuaJIT (which can be assumed to do similiar optimizations) except if you have *really many* levels. Note also that you may simply achieve the same by properly nesting your `if`s, which will have much less overhead.